# Issue connecting Microsoft Access to Active Directory

Tags: ms-access, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to connect Active Directory to Microsoft Access 2010 using the LDAP string to import data into a database, which is queried by ASP. Even though I am looking to return contact details, i.e. firstname, lastname, email, phone number, etc. Due to not being sure what the field names I am looking for, I am just doing the following to begin with:

```
SELECT * FROM 'LDAP://OU=Users,DC=example,DC=internal'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM 'LDAP://OU=Users, DC=example,DC=co,DC=uk'
```

I have, obviously, replaced the OU and DC values with dummy values. In both cases I am getting a syntax error, 'incorrect query string' and am struggling to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some code in the code bank over at dbForums that might help you out.

http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1605962-DBForums-Code-Bank&p=6296643#post6296643

Comment: sorry for the delay, but it looks like you solved it.